# PHP progress bar for termux

Tags: php, termux

Here is a code for progress bar for termux:

```
<?php
$iloop = "0"; /* Outside the loop */
while (true){  
    $warn = "Program running  holdd on!!\r";
    if (strlen($warn) === $iloop+1){
        $iloop = "0";
    }
    $warn = str_split($warn);
    $iloop++;
    $warn[$iloop] = "\033[ 35;2m\e[0m".strtoupper($warn[$iloop]);
    echo "\033[7m".implode($warn);
    usleep(90000);
}
```

This keeps repeating. I want it to stop after 20 sec and then start printing my remaining code. So how can I stop it after 20 seconds?

Comment: `$iloop = "0";` change this to `$iloop = 0;` coz in loop your incrementing the `$iloop` by one so it should be a `int` not `char`

Answer (score 0):

```
$iloop = 0; /* Outside the loop */
while (true){  
  $warn = "Program running  holdd on!!\r";
  if (strlen($warn) === $iloop+1){
    $iloop = 0;
  }
  $warn = str_split($warn);
  $iloop++;
  $warn[$iloop] = "\033[ 35;2m\e[0m".strtoupper($warn[$iloop]);
  echo "\033[7m".implode($warn);
  usleep(90000);
}
```

as I mentioned in the comment your `$iloop` variable holds the string value of 0 so as it enters into the loop it's not getting incremented, so just change the `$iloop='0'` to `$iloop=0`.

here read more about [data types](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_datatypes.asp),